# Remove Content-Type header from Lighttpd response

Tags: php, lighttpd

I have written a function called IO::stdout:

```
class IO {
      public static function stdout($var) {
          $stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
          fwrite($stdout, $var, strlen($var));
          fclose($stdout);
      }
}
IO::stdout("Hello World!");
```

Well, it works! But when I request the page, it displays me:

```
Hello World!
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.13
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Setting `expose_php = Off` in php.ini removed the X-Powered-By header, but the Content-Type header is still printed. It is probably added by Lighttpd. How do I disable the Content-Type header?

Comment: lighttpd adds "Content-Type" not "Content-type" to headers (before the body content -- and so whatever is adding "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" is not lighttpd.  It appears that your PHP code conflicts with the default PHP handling of the request, as the headers appearing after your "Hello World!" look like headers that PHP would send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default PHP header: http://php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.default-mimetype

You can't remove it using `header_remove`, as a missing `Content-Type` header will trigger the default mime-type.

Instead, try to set it to an empty string:

`header('Content-Type:', true);`

`true` will erase any previous similar header.

And just for the record, headers' names are case insensitive, and PHP is known to send the `Content-type` with a small `t`.

Also you can send the right `Content-Type` (which should be `text/plain` I think).